# Continuous looping animation scroll uing ReactJS ans CSS

Tags: reactjs, scroll, css-animations, infinite-scroll

I have to create a continuously looping animation scroll using React and CSS. The goal is to create an automatic scroll and continuous looping the list, so after the last element of the list I should have the first element and so on, this is what I've got for the moment:

[image]

The problem I have now is when the last element scrolled I get a blank page and should wait 3 or 4 second before looping again and again, and I want to get item 1 just after Item 5 and so on..not sure if it's clear, this is my code for the moment :

```js
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card.js";

import "./styles.css";

let data = [
  {
    Name: "1"
  },
  {
    Name: "2"
  },

  {
    Name: "3"
  },

  {
    Name: "4"
  },

  {
    Name: "5"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [containerWidth, setWidth] = useState(100 + "%");
  const [animationState, setPlay] = useState("paused");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      setWidth(ref.current.scrollWidth + "px");
      setPlay("running");
    }
  }, []);
  console.log(containerWidth);
  const renderCards = data.map((el, index) => {
    return <Card key={index} cardName={el.Name} />;
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="d-flex"
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          width: `${containerWidth}`,
          animationPlayState: animationState
        }}
      >
        {renderCards}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card {
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ffefef;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(158, 151, 151, 0.25);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
}
.d-flex {
  transform: translateY(calc(100vw));
  overflow: visible;
  animation: animateContainer 5s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes animateContainer {
  from {
    transform: translateY(calc(100vw));
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100%));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And this is [my sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-brook-hr5x4l?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

Have a copy of the list of items under the first list. Reset the animation when the copy reaches the top. For most intents and purposes, this will make it look endless. Animate between `translateY(0)` where the top of the list is at the top, to `translateY(-50%)` where the top of the copy of the list at the top:

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, useState } = React;

function Card({ cardName, refCard }) {
  return (
    <div className="bubble" ref={refCard}>
      <div className="card m-2 pt-2">
        <div className="py-1">
          <div className="fs-5 mt-2">{cardName}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

let data = [
  {
    Name: "1"
  },
  {
    Name: "2"
  },

  {
    Name: "3"
  },

  {
    Name: "4"
  },

  {
    Name: "5"
  }
];

function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [containerWidth, setWidth] = useState(100 + "%");
  const [animationState, setPlay] = useState("paused");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      setWidth(ref.current.scrollWidth + "px");
      setPlay("running");
    }
  }, []);
  console.log(containerWidth);
  const renderCards = data.map((el, index) => {
    return <Card key={index} cardName={el.Name} />;
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="d-flex"
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          width: `${containerWidth}`,
          animationPlayState: animationState
        }}
      >
        {renderCards}
        {renderCards}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```css
.App {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card {
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ffefef;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgba(158, 151, 151, 0.25);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
}
.d-flex {
  overflow: visible;
  animation: animateContainer 5s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes animateContainer {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, there is another solution without duplicating liste items ?

Comment: Yes, you could look at using [`html2canvas`](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to create visual duplicates without duplicating the list items.

Comment: Ok thank's, have you any sample example please of using this ?

Comment: No, I don't have an example.

Comment: Hi, I faced some problem with this solution, there is another way to do it without '5s linear forwards infinite' bcause in case of 50 items it's impossible to show it all in only 5s..

Comment: Yes, you could change the duration to your needs.

Comment: When I change the duration the speed change too, I want to have the same speed, please take a look  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76991708/reactjs-continuous-looping-animation-scroll?noredirect=1#comment135726393_76991708

Comment: Changing the duration would indeed change the speed, since speed = distance ÷ time. Thus, if you want to keep the speed the same, adjust the distance.